# Get PixelColor at Top/Left Pos to Change TIme String On Screensaver

Tags: vb.net, graphics, colors, pixel

I was told to edit the program up here, so here is small program that shows what I am trying to accomplish (learn)
I am using the screen.Bounds as you suggested, but the problem is still that the mouse gets it's location only when it is within the form.  Outside of the form the mouse has no clue where it is, and therefore cant tell me the color at its mouse position.

I feel I'm so close to getting this to work...

```
Public Class Form10

    'Sample Code
    'Needs 2 Textboxes, names txtStatic, txtMouse
    'Needs 2 Pictureboxes, names PBStatic, PBMouse
    'Needs Timer1 set to 1000
    'Goal is to show pixelcolor of screen under
    'form's corner, top/left at Point(450,74) "named STATIC"
    'and show color of Screen Pixel when mouse is clicked
    'anywhere on Screen "named MOUSE"

    Dim ScreenX, ScreenY As Integer
    Dim SColor, MColor As Color
    Dim MouseLoc, StaticLoc As Point

    Private Sub Form10_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                            Handles Me.Load
        Me.Location = New Point(450, 75)
        StaticLoc = Me.Location
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ScreenX = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Width
        ScreenY = My.Computer.Screen.Bounds.Height
        Dim bm As New Bitmap(ScreenX, ScreenY)
        SColor = GetPixColor(StaticLoc)
        MColor = GetPixColor(MouseLoc)
        TxtStatic.Text = StaticLoc.ToString
        TxtMouse.Text = MouseLoc.ToString
        PBStatic.BackColor = SColor
        PBMouse.BackColor = MColor
    End Sub

    Function GetPixColor(ByVal Location As Point) As Color
        Using b As New Bitmap(1, 1)
            Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b)
                g.CopyFromScreen(Location, Point.Empty, New Drawing.Size(1, 1))
            End Using
            Return b.GetPixel(0, 0)
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Sub Form10_MouseMove(sender As Object,
                                 e As MouseEventArgs) _
                                 Handles Me.MouseMove
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim x1, y1 As Integer
            x1 = e.Location.X - mouseloc.X
            y1 = e.Location.Y - mouseloc.Y
            Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + x1,
                                    Me.Location.Y + y1)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form10_MouseClick(sender As Object,
                                  e As MouseEventArgs) _
                                  Handles Me.MouseClick
        MouseLoc = e.Location
    End Sub

End Class
```

HERE IS THE DESIGNER IN CASE SOMETHING IS WRONG THERE TOO !!

```
_
Partial Class Form10
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.Timer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
        Me.PBMouse = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.TxtMouse = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.TxtStatic = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.PBStatic = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.Label3 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        CType(Me.PBMouse, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        CType(Me.PBStatic, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'Timer1
        '
        Me.Timer1.Interval = 1000
        '
        'PBMouse
        '
        Me.PBMouse.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(35, 341)
        Me.PBMouse.Name = "PBMouse"
        Me.PBMouse.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(337, 50)
        Me.PBMouse.TabIndex = 8
        Me.PBMouse.TabStop = False
        '
        'TxtMouse
        '
        Me.TxtMouse.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 16.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.TxtMouse.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(35, 260)
        Me.TxtMouse.Name = "TxtMouse"
        Me.TxtMouse.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(337, 64)
        Me.TxtMouse.TabIndex = 7
        '
        'TxtStatic
        '
        Me.TxtStatic.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 16.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.TxtStatic.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(35, 109)
        Me.TxtStatic.Name = "TxtStatic"
        Me.TxtStatic.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(337, 64)
        Me.TxtStatic.TabIndex = 6
        '
        'PBStatic
        '
        Me.PBStatic.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(35, 43)
        Me.PBStatic.Name = "PBStatic"
        Me.PBStatic.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(337, 50)
        Me.PBStatic.TabIndex = 5
        Me.PBStatic.TabStop = False
        '
        'Label1
        '
        Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(39, 14)
        Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
        Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(72, 29)
        Me.Label1.TabIndex = 9
        Me.Label1.Text = "Static"
        '
        'Label3
        '
        Me.Label3.AutoSize = True
        Me.Label3.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.Label3.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(39, 224)
        Me.Label3.Name = "Label3"
        Me.Label3.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(128, 29)
        Me.Label3.TabIndex = 11
        Me.Label3.Text = "MousePos"
        '
        'Form10
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(12.0!, 25.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(412, 450)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label3)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PBMouse)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TxtMouse)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TxtStatic)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PBStatic)
        Me.Name = "Form10"
        Me.Text = "Form10"
        Me.TopMost = True
        CType(Me.PBMouse, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        CType(Me.PBStatic, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents Timer1 As Timer
    Friend WithEvents PBMouse As PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents TxtMouse As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents TxtStatic As TextBox
    Friend WithEvents PBStatic As PictureBox
    Friend WithEvents Label1 As Label
    Friend WithEvents Label3 As Label
End Class
```

Comment: `NewLoc = New Point(CInt(LblTime.Left), CInt(LblTime.Top))` returns a value that is always relative to the position of the Label inside its parent Form. Assume it `(2, 2)`: you always get one Pixel at `(4, 4)` of the current Screen, not what's under the Label. Use the Form's Bounds to get Form's offset inside the Screen. You should probably use a transparent Form so you can actually get a copy what's under it. Then only change the Label's foreground. Note that the *inversion formula* is not exactly functional. Maybe read the average luminance of the pixels under your Form.

Comment: Thanks Jimi.  I changed the NewLoc point to screen.bounds, but that didn't work. I am still having the problem that outside the little form the mouse does not return its position and therefore cannot get the pixel color.  I wrote this small program to demonstrate the problem. Also, I don't understand what you mean by Transparent Form. The form's property does not allow the transparent color as a background color.  Tony

Comment: Basic transparency is achieved setting the Form's BackColor and TransparencyKey to the same Color value. Different Colors may produce different results (as Magenta, for example - some colors cause the Mouse pointer to click through your Form). You cannot use the `MouseMove` event (also, the Mouse Pointer location is actually irrelevant). Setting the color random of a random pixel won't produce good results anyway. You should paint to the Screen directly.

Comment: Thank you. Making the forms BackColor did the trick, and painting directly to the screen worked a lot better than using label.  Thank you so much.